# Force Glassfish 4 to generate 2.0 wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, wsdl, glassfish-4

By default @Webservice on Glassfish 4 generates wsdl 1.1.

**How can I force Glassfish 4 to generate 2.0 wsdl ?**

To me it seems impossible, please confirm or deny below arguments:

Glassfish 4 uses metro implementation, jax-ws 2.2
https://jax-ws.java.net/

latest jsr about jax-ws 2.2 states https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr224/index4.html

> WSDL 2.0
>   The W3C is expected to progress WSDL 2.0[13] to Recommendati
>   on during the lifetime of this
>   JSR. JAX-WS 2.0 will add support for WSDL 2.0 whilst requirin
>   g continued support for WSDL 1.1.

page 2:

> Note:
>   The expert group for the JSR decided against this goal for thi
>   s release . We will look at adding
>   support in a future revision of the JAX-WS specification.

page 157, changes:

> Removed references to WSDL 2.0 and updated goals to reflect W
>   SDL 2.0 support will be added a
>   future revision of the specification.

page 160:

> Removed WSDL 2.0 mapping (appendices A and B).